# UIPopoverPresentation without arrow

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, xcode, uipopovercontroller

I am trying to present a `UIViewController` in an `UIPopoverPresentationController` but I dont really like the arrow feature.

Basically what I want to do is to use an `UIPopoverPresentationController without the arrow` that comes with it.

I am coding in Swift.

Comment: As far as I know you cant use UIPopoverPresentationController without arrow. The only way - use/create other class.

Comment: Could you tell me where/what to search then ?

Comment: No I can't, I love that arrow, sorry :D

Comment: @ShadowOf You can definitely do it. I have posted the answer below for you. Be positive, there is nothing you cant do. :)

Comment: @ManjulShrestha nice! my comments useless then =)

Comment: @ShadowOf did not mean to do that. Cheers :)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

This is what I tackled just a few days back. What I did was basically remove the arrow and provided a source rect myself. The source, of course, had its Y position altered to give it a popover effect without the arrow. Try it, worked like a charm for me.

```
yourPopoverPresentationController!.permittedArrowDirections = UIPopoverArrowDirection.init(rawValue: 0)
let aView = //Source View that you would provide for the source rect
yourPopoverPresentationController!.sourceView = aView
let position = CGRectMake(aView.bounds.origin.x, aView.bounds.origin.y + 125, aView.bounds.size.width, aView.bounds.size.height)
yourPopoverPresentationController!.sourceRect = position
```

This resulted in the following effect which was what I required. 
[image]

Comment: the arrow comes on top of the view for me